# How to check the number of CPUs and cores from host with virsh?

Tags: virtualization, virtualhost, virsh

How to check the number of CPUs and cores available in the host machine using `virsh`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `virsh nodeinfo`. The output will be something like:

```
CPU model                    x86_64
CPU (s)                      8
CPU frequency                2895 Mhz
CPU socket(s)                2      
Core(s) per socket           2
Threads per core:            2
Numa cell(s)                 1
Memory size:                 1046528 kb
```

*Source: https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Virtualization/chap-Virtualization-Managing_guests_with_virsh.html*

Alternatively, you can run the `lscpu` command.

Comment: Is there a simple command similar to `virsh nodeinfo` which shows the exact same layout, but currently allocated CPU and memory count?

Answer (score 0):

to see the full set of what the host can offer, run `virsh capabilities`. The `<cpus num...>` field will hold the number, followed by the listing of cores/sockets/threads etc.